# gazebo_ros_turtlebot3.cpp with real robot (waffle)

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know why the `gazebo_ros_turtlebot3.cpp`, used to make the turtlebot3 autonomously navigates in the gazebo 3D, does not work with the real robot? I am using a turtlebot3 waffle. What changes do I have to make in the cpp code, or in the launch file, in order to make it works with the real robot?

What I mean is, if I run `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch` and after that I run `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_simulation.launch`  the turtlebot3 navigates into the simulator. But, if I run `roscore` in the pc, and, after that, I  run `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch` in the turtlebot3 waffle, and then run `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_simulation.launch`  the turtlebot3 does not navegate, it just  spins around itself. But, if i run `roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch`, I can teleoperate the robot normaly using the keyboard.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281079/gazebo_ros_turtlebot3.cpp-with-real-robot-(waffle)/) by [RubensQRZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/33451/rubensqrz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is the simulator. The launch file `turtlebot3_simulation.launch` is designed to work within the simulation not in the real robot. `turtlebot3_simulation.launch` is a demo that will help you see a fully functioning system in the simulation.

For instructinos on how to bring up the TB3 please see: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/bringup/#turtlebot3-waffle

There are other sections with instructions on how to setup navigation: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/navigation/#perform-navigation

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0